# Create custom item in jsTree Context menu

Tags: asp.net-mvc, treeview, jstree

I create a treeview using jsTree with contextmenu in asp.net mvc3.

```
<div id="divtree">
<ul id="tree">
    <li><a href="#" class="usr">@Model.Name</a>
        @Html.Partial("Childrens", Model)
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#divtree").jstree(
        {
            "plugins": ["themes", "html_data", "ui", "crrm", "contextmenu"]
        });
});
```

it's works fine.

[image]

I want to create a custom item in the context menu. For example create a new menu item. New for create new Employee in the context menu, and insert the employee in DB. I use a jQuery POST function for this task. But how to handle the click event in the Context menu item.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) and what is your question?

Comment: Sorry, I explain my question...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here's how you could customize the contextmenu plugin:

```
$("#divtree").jstree({
    "plugins": ["themes", "html_data", "ui", "crrm", "contextmenu"],
    "contextmenu": {
        "items": function ($node) {
            return {
                "Create": {
                    "label": "Create a new employee",
                    "action": function (obj) {
                        this.create(obj);
                    }
                },
                "Rename": {
                    "label": "Rename an employee",
                    "action": function (obj) {
                        this.rename(obj);
                    }
                },
                "Delete": {
                    "label": "Delete an employee",
                    "action": function (obj) {
                        this.remove(obj);
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
});
```

Alright, in this example I am only calling the base function inside the click handlers: `this.create(obj);`, `this.rename(obj);` and `this.remove(obj);` where `obj` will be the node that was clicked.

So now for example if you want to send an AJAX request to the server when a new item is added you could subscribe to the `create.jstree` event as shown in the [`demo page`](http://www.jstree.com/demo) of the jsTree documentation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#divtree").jstree({
        "plugins": ["themes", "html_data", "ui", "crrm", "contextmenu"],
        "contextmenu": {
            "items": function ($node) {
                return {
                    "Create": {
                        "label": "Create a new employee",
                        "action": function (obj) {
                            this.create(obj);
                        }
                    },
                    "Rename": {
                        "label": "Rename an employee",
                        "action": function (obj) {
                            this.rename(obj);
                        }
                    },
                    "Delete": {
                        "label": "Delete an employee",
                        "action": function (obj) {
                            this.remove(obj);
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        }
    })
    .bind("create.jstree", function (e, data) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("create", "employees")", 
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                "name" : data.rslt.name
            },
            success: function (result) {
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Inspect the `e` and `data` arguments that are passed to the `create.jstree` event callback. They contain lots of useful information about the newly created node that you could use to send along with the AJAX request.

Inspired by this example you could continue extending it with the `remove.jstree` and `rename.jstree` events as shown in the documentation. So when you look at it, all that was needed was to read the documentation. For example I've never used jsTree in my life but 5 minutes was all that it took me to find the example in the documentation and do a quick spike for you. So next time you have a programming related question about some plugin or framework that you are using please put more efforts into reading the documentation first.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir, I am first time using Treeview,

Sure, I must read all documentation carefully, 

Again said Thank you for your valueable effort.

Comment: I am facing a new problem in 'create.jstree' event. 

" data.rslt.new_name " (used for getting new text in the node)  is null this event.

Comment: I Solve this issue. I use " data.rslt.name " instead " data.rslt.new_name".

Comment: when I've tried this code firebug catch error / this.create is not a function/. Using jsTree v. 3.1.1. What's wrong ?

Comment: @loviji check what `this` contains. I had the same issue and it was a pointer to the window object `[object Window]`. Replace it with a reference to the jstree itself and it should work.

Comment: here is version working in 3.2.1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096141/jstree-and-context-menu-modify-items/32329493#32329493