# jsTree to send a Ajax request to web-service when new node is added

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, treeview, jstree, treeviewitem

I am using jsTree, and on adding a new item to the tree, i  want to send an AJAX request to the server when a new item is added.

Here's what i found [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14133984/create-custom-item-in-jstree-context-menu) , on searching

I want the Ajax request to be sent to a vb.net web-service, this is done by using  create.jstree event as shown in the link above.

But what will my web-service consist of? I want the web-service to know and save the changes(new node added, deleted or renamed).

Can anybody help me out on this?